# Query top ranked values from sum with joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written a query which output the sale figures of all employees, and their name and what shop they work at. But I am trying to find the top sales person for **each shop**. Can you please explain how can i only show the top sales person for each shop. I was thinking that i can use

```
SELECT empname, shopname, SUM( rentalrate ) AS Sales
FROM frs_FilmRental
NATURAL JOIN frs_Employee
NATURAL JOIN frs_Shop
GROUP BY empnin, shopname
```

Here is screenshot of my 
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gl2as.png) so far

Comment: There's no DISTINCT function in SQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Given two tables, select all data from one table and only the most recent from the other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40979927/given-two-tables-select-all-data-from-one-table-and-only-the-most-recent-from-t)

Comment: This question may be a duplicate, but given the complexity of the query I doubt the OP would get the answet right on his own.  Add to the complexity that MySQL does not have cte or row number.

Comment: i think we can make this query a bit more efficient could you post the columns in the Employee Table, Shop Table and Film Rental and i should then be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really ugly way:

```
SELECT t1.empname,
       t1.shopname,
       t2.maxsales
FROM
(
    SELECT empname, shopname, SUM(rentalrate) AS sales
    FROM frs_FilmRental
    NATURAL JOIN frs_Employee
    NATURAL JOIN frs_Shop
    GROUP BY empname, shopname
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t.shopname, MAX(t.Sales) AS maxsales
    FROM
    (
        SELECT shopname, SUM(rentalrate) AS Sales
        FROM frs_FilmRental
        NATURAL JOIN frs_Employee
        NATURAL JOIN frs_Shop
        GROUP BY empname, shopname
    ) t
    GROUP BY t.shopname
) t2
    ON t1.shopname = t2.shopname AND
       t1.sales    = t2.maxsales
```

You will recognize the subquery `t1` as simply being your original query.  The `t2` subquery restricts this result set to only those shops which had the highest sales, implying only the record corresponding to the employeee with the highest sales.  In the event of a tie, both records would be returned for that shop.

The query is a bit verbose, but this owes in part to that MySQL does not have support for row number or common table expressions.

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT *
    FROM
    (
      SELECT DISTINCT empname, shopname,
      SUM( rentalrate ) OVER (PARTITION BY shopname,empname ) AS Sales,
      ROW_NUMBER OVER (PARTITION BY shopname,empname ) AS RN
      FROM frs_FilmRental
      NATURAL JOIN frs_Employee
      NATURAL JOIN frs_Shop
      GROUP BY empnin, shopname 
                                 ) X
    WHERE X.RN=1
```

Comment: This leaves you with only the best sales person, but not the best for every shop.

Comment: @Seb Updated my answer.